# Find exponential generating function for recurrence

Tags: combinatorics

I have a recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} + (n-1)a_{n-2}, a_0=1, a_1=1$.  I am trying to find the exponential generating function for this but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: I basically don't know how to start, I know how to do this for OGF's but I don't where to go for EGF's.  I know I need to start by defining the EGF for $a_n$ as $A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write the recurrence relation in the more convenient form $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + (n+1)a_n$. Now you need to translate that information into something about the exponential generating function $A(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$ of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$.

This means we want to relate the exponential generating functions of the sequences $(a_{n+2})_{n \ge 0}$, $(a_{n+1})_{n \ge 0}$ and $((n+1)a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ to that of the sequence $(a_n)$.

First you can check that

$$A'(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n!} nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a_{n+1}}{n!} x^n$$

and similarly, with the same computation we have $A^{''}(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a_{n+2}}{n!} x^n$. And we can also check that

$$(xA(x))' = \left(\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a_{n}}{n!} x^{n+1}\right)' = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(n+1)a_{n}}{n!} x^n$$

So we get $A''(x) = A'(x) + (xA(x))'$. I'll leave you the rest (solving the equation, and translating $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$ into information about $A$).

Comment: I am getting somewhere but it's been a while since calculus.  I have $A(x) = \frac{A'(x)}{1+x}$ but i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @Mroog : To solve a differential of the form $y' = f y$, compute a primitive $F$ of $f$ and notice $e^F$ is a particular solution of your equation.

Answer (score 5):

My preferred approach starts by rewriting the recurrence so that it holds for all $n\ge 0$ on the assumption that $a_n=0$ for $n<0$:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2}+[n=0]\;,\tag{1}$$

where the last term is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Then multiply $(1)$ by $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and sum over $n$; if $A(x)=\sum_na_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is the desired egf, we have

$$\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\sum_na_{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_n(n-1)a_{n-2}\frac{x^n}{n!}+1\\
&=\sum_n\left(\frac{a_{n-1}}n\cdot\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}\right)+\sum_n\left(\frac{a_{n-2}}n\cdot\frac{x^n}{(n-2)!}\right)+1\\
&=\sum_n\left(\frac{a_n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\right)+\sum_n\left(\frac{a_n}{n+2}\cdot\frac{x^{n+2}}{n!}\right)+1\;.\tag{2}
\end{align*}$$

Now observe that differentiating $(2)$ would get rid of the factors of $n+1$ and $n+2$ in the denominators of the summations, making them look much more like $A(x)$ itself. In fact, we get

$$A'(x)=A(x)+\sum_n\left(a_n\cdot\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\right)=A(x)+xA(x)=(x+1)A(x)\;,$$

a nice separable differential equation. Separating the variables yields

$$\frac{A'(x)}{A(x)}=x+1\;,$$

and after integrating both sides we have

$$\ln A(x)=\frac{x^2}2+x+C\;,$$

or

$$A(x)=e^C\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2+x\right)\;.$$

Finally, $e^C=A(0)=a_0=1$, so

$$A(x)=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}2+x\right)\;.$$